# Is it true that Lisp is not a functional programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, lisp

I read in the book: "Masterminds of programming" , the the interview with Guido Van  Rossum says:

> *The more fundamental property Python shares with Lisp ( not a functional language either! ) is that functionas are first-class objects*...

So, Lisp is **not** a functional programming language?

Is Guido wrong?  What is it then?

Comment: setq setq setq setq

Comment: I can't see how is this "subjective" the language is either *a functional programming* or not.

Comment: There is no formal definition of when a language qualifies as a functional programming language, so it depends on your point of view. Generally one would say a functional programming language is one which discourages mutation and emphasizes a declarative style of programming (often using higher order functions and recursion). By that definition both python and lisp are about equally functional - both have higher order functions and other declarative ways to express loops, but both also have commonly used primitives for mutation and do not require tail recursion optimization.

Comment: It is interesting to note that the [original, minimal lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html) *doesn't* have `setq`. It is not part of what makes lisp lisp, rather a thing added to most implementation to make it easier to do certain things.

Comment: @sepp2k Thanks for the explaination.

Comment: Lisp is not a programming language, but a family of programming languages. Clojure is a functional Lisp. On the other hand, Common Lisp does support functional features, but the use of imperative techniques is more pervasive in Common Lisp programs.

Comment: When someone refers to 'Lisp' as a language, they're probably referring to Common Lisp (Which is what Guido has done in his quoted statement here, I think.)

Comment: @CharlieFlowers Voted to re-open. This question can be answered with facts, expertise and references, if necessary.

Answer (score 25):

Pretty much every Lisp I know of can be used to program in a functional style (all you really need are first-class functions, after all!)

However, Lisps are more like multi-language toolkits: you can do functional programming, OOP, logic programming, define your own DSL for some whacky new paradigm etc.

The Lisp that is probably closest to a functional programming style is Clojure (it has lazy evaluation, discourages OOP, uses immutable data structures throughout, restricts uncontrolled mutation (via STM), has quite a lot of pure / higher order functions in the core library etc.)

Answer (score 10):

There are languages that allow and encourage functional programming paradigms. Both Python and Lisp are among these. Lisp in particular was the first one to apply theoretical concepts derived from lambda calculus. In the late 1950s, when almost only FORTRAN and Lisp existed, Lisp was highlighted as the functional one, where FORTRAN, with a fully static memory management, would never be considered functional.

However, neither Python nor Lisp *enforce* pure functionality, allowing mutable variables, states and imperative constructs. A mixture of styles can always be handy in practice, so probably you will not find many example of *pure* concepts in very successful tools.

Among purely functional languages, Haskell, Clean and Miranda are listed examples, but I cannot say anything about them.

Comment: In fact, both Python and Common Lisp enforce imperative programming. Both won't ever guarantee a proper tail recursion handling, so you *have*  to use imperative loops.