# How do you iterate in functional languages?

Tags: functional-programming, imperative-programming

One reason that pushes me away from functional languages like Lisp is that I have no idea how to do a 'raw' array iteration. Say, I have an array in C that represents the screen pixels's RGB values. Changing colors is trivial with a for loop in C, but how do you do this elegantly in Lisp?

EDIT:

Sorry, I haven't phrased my question correctly. 
In C, when I want to change color on the screen, I simply write a for loop over a part of the array.
BUT in scheme, clojure or haskell all data is immutable. So when I change a part of matrix, it would return a brand new matrix. That's a bit awkward. Is there a 'clean' way to change the color of a part of matrix without recursing over whole array and making copies?

Comment: What makes you think Lisp is a "functional language"? (c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021649/is-it-true-that-lisp-is-not-a-functional-programming-language )

Comment: It's even trivialler in Lisp, since the loop design pattern can be abstracted out into suitable "map" procedures which do the looping for you.

Answer (score 1):

In a functional language, you would use recursion.
The recursion scheme can be named.

For example, to recurse over an array of data, applying a function to each pixel, you can manually recurse over the structure of the array:

```
map f []     = []             
      -- the empty array
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs  
      -- apply f to the head of the array, and loop on the tail.
```

(in Haskell).

This recursive form is so common it is called `map` in most libraries.

Answer (score 0):

To "iterate" through an array in some language like Lisp is a simple map.
The structure is `(map f x)` where f is a function you want applied to every element of the list/array x.